# Selected image in a TogglerBar changes outline colour

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I have a `TogglerBar` control for selecting images, but I see inconsistent border colours depending on what else is in the `Dynamic`.

```
images = ExampleData[{"TestImage", #}] & /@ {"Mandrill", "Peppers", "Tiffany"}
```

If I just have a single TogglerBar then the images are outlined in grey, so are not very visible:

```
 DynamicModule[{c = {}}, 
   Column[{TogglerBar[Dynamic[c], images, Appearance -> "Row"]}]]
```

[image]

Whereas if I have a Column with any other object, the images are outlined in a nice clear blue:

```
 DynamicModule[{c = {}},  
   Column[{TogglerBar[Dynamic[c], images, Appearance -> "Row"], Dynamic@Length@c}]]
```

[image]

Is this a bug? I'm using v11.3.0 on macOS.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Linux with 11.3

Comment: @halirutan, is it always blue for you?

Comment: No, always like in your top image

Comment: On Win everything is ok. The frame is blue (lighter than here) if you select them but for an empty `c` it is gray.

Comment: I find the two-shades of grey hard to distinguish, and would much rather it was blue. Is there a way to set the colour?

Comment: Anyone know how to set the outline colour directly? I've tried variations of `BaseStyle` but can't figure out what to use.